# Everytime ask for login when git command

Tags: git, github

I used personal token to clone private repository,then when I commit or push changes, there would a window ask for login github.

Where can I setting so that don't need to login by browser everytimes?

The ask window is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once signed-in (preferably with a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)), Git should not ask for your credentials again.

Check that `git config --global credential.helper` is set to `manager`.
That would use the [GCM (Git Credential Manager)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) from Microsoft (a cross-platform credential manager).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh to use SSH. Once you have setup the key on your device and on your GitHub account, you can clone, pull, commit, push and etc. using this SSH key instead of your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

**Open Terminal/CMD**
Set Username and email configuration once

> git config --global user.name "here your username"
> git config --global user.email "here your useremail"

After running this command your credential will save in git.
then you can push and pull your code easily.

**For more details you can take a look**
[Example of configure useremail and username in git](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-your-dvcs-username-for-commits/)

Comment: No, `user.name`/`user.email` are only for local commit authorship. They have 0 (zero) impact on HTTPS credentials.